# How to open aspx page in bootstrap modal popup without iframe

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to open aspx page in bootstrap modal popup. but failed! anyone can help? page post back no meter.

Comment: Try using JqueryUi http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: bootstrap model dosn't use iFrame ( yak!) http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I approved bootstrap modal form client. so i can use just bootstrap modal. i can use iframe. and its work fine. but i don't want to use iframe. any other idea u have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery .ajax() method, or shorthand .load() method to get your content and append it to your bootstrap modal, here's simple jsfiddle(using jQuery load() method):
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/j941pe1h/)
`$('#myModal .modal-body').load( "https://fiddle.jshell.net/" );`

If you are loading content from different domain, you have to adjust your response headers or use JSONP. [Cross origin resource sharing documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Can you share your code? Are there any errors in your browser console?